# Apple script runs into error: "Can’t make missing value into type document or tab" if you move away from the page

Tags: applescript

I run the script below to do some web scraping and it works well until do anything else while the script is running. The moment I do something else the following error appears:

> error "Safari got an error: Can’t make missing value into type document or tab."

How can I resolve this issue?

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    repeat with a from 1 to 159
        open location "https://google.com" & a 
        delay 1
        set keyword to "test"
        set myWindow to current tab of first window
        activate
        
        do JavaScript "window.location.reload()" in myWindow
        
        repeat while (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is not "complete"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        
        set pageContent to do JavaScript ("window.document.documentElement.outerHTML") in myWindow
        
        if pageContent contains keyword then
            display dialog "found it"
            exit repeat
        end if
        delay 2 -- wait a bit before running again
        close myWindow
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Obviously its currently coded to require **Safari** to be and stay the frontmost _application_. Aside from the fact that your _script_ as coded cannot be practically tested as the **URL** it creates is just a malformed variant of _google.com_, if you want it to run in the background then recode it to do so!

Answer (score 0):

In my testing I did not see any AppleScript errors; this script as written seems to work fine, though it never finds the keyword in question. Of course, I'm on Catalina; if you're on a different OS, can you specify? Or can you post a script that doesn't have test code (e.g., `open location "https://google.com" & a`, which clearly does nothing), and that you are absolutely sure produces an error for you?

I'd suggest a rewrite as follows, for the moment:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set myWindow to current tab of first window
    repeat with a from 1 to 159
        open location "https://google.com" & a
        delay 1
        set keyword to "test"
        
        do JavaScript "window.location.reload()" in myWindow
        
        repeat while (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is not "complete"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        
        set pageContent to do JavaScript ("window.document.documentElement.outerHTML") in myWindow
        
        if pageContent contains keyword then
            display dialog "found it"
            exit repeat
        end if
        delay 2 -- wait a bit before running again
        close myWindow
    end repeat
end tell
```

All this does is remove the `activate` commands so that Safari stays in the background, and moves the line that sets the window out of the repeat loop, so that the reference is only set once.

There are other suggestions I could make (for instance, this would be much more efficient as a script application than a script), but save those for now.

Comment: The principles you've explained are solid, but the starting assumption is incorrect (well, partly): `set myWindow to current tab of first window` is evaluated at the point of assignment, so whichever specific `tab` object was the `current tab` at the time will be the object reference that is assigned to `myWindow`, independent of what subsequent values `current tab` takes on. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ However, Safari has no way of doing what you inferred would be (and should be) possible to create a static reference a `tab` object that will remain invariant throughout the lifespan of the tab. Moreover, for some inane reason, AppleScript doesn't care how one references the `tab`, as it will always convert it to its `index` key form, and this is dependent on the ordering of the tabs. The end result is that all three of the variable assignments you demonstrated above—`myWindow`, and the two (not-so-)`staticTab`s—will, unfortunately, contain exactly the same values.

Comment: @CJK: well, I still think the problem is with the way he uses `current tab`, even if what you say is correct. He needs to make and hold a static reference to the tab he wants to work with. But we're both working on short evidence here; let's wait to see if the OP responds or updates his question.

Comment: When I say “move away from the page” I mean I stop actively view safari and actively view another application. For example, I’m on safari while the script is running and then I go to check my email without canceling the script. I will then throw that exception.

Comment: Ted, sorry, I was trying to say that there _is no such thing_ as a static reference to a `tab` object in Safari (at least, pre-Big Sur). `id` key-formed references are the only truly static reference in AppleScript, but Safari `tab`s lack an `id` property. So, while I do totally agree with your train of thought, it’s just not possible. It’s weird that the error message complains of a `missing value`—I can’t think of a situation where a window’s `current tab` property would be `missing value`. @sfsdfsdfsdfsd, try using `document 1` instead of `myWindow` except in the `close` command.

Comment: @CJK: I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm simply waiting for the OP to respond (which he has) so that I can modify my answer.  I'll take your points into account, no worries.